# Cannot set a MouseEvent for MenuItem to trigger a ContextMenu. What would be an alternative solution?

Tags: java, javafx, menu

Given the EventHandler code:

```
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> MEvent = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getButton() ==  MouseButton.PRIMARY) 
                System.out.println("FIRE LEFT MB");
            }
            else if (arg0.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                System.out.println("FIRE RIGHT MB");
            }
        }
    };
```

Unfortunately, when doing a setOnAction for a menuItem through gets()

```
MenuBar().getMenus().get(a).getItems().get(b).addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, MEvent);
```

It will never fire. Apparently this has something to do with specific implementation of *MenuItem*. Is there anything that I can wrap the *MenuItem* in so that it can take a MouseEvent and it can still be added in *Menus*?

Is it possible to use ActionEvent with more specificity?

Perhaps a filter is the way to go?

Comment: Can you make a full example that compiles? Maybe a CustomMenuItem that doesn't get hidden on click?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check which mouse button was pressed, you can use simply `setOnAction`.

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Click here");
menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
menuItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("On Action"));
```

If you want a real mouse handler to be attached, you can try to make a `CustomMenuItem` with a `Label` as graphic, and then you can attach any listener on that `Label`:

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");

Label customMenuLabel = new Label("Custom menu item");
CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(customMenuLabel);

customMenuLabel.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
    if (event.getButton() ==  MouseButton.PRIMARY)
        System.out.println("FIRE LEFT MB");
    else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
        System.out.println("FIRE RIGHT MB");
});

menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using CustomMenuItem before, but I ran into problem of fetching it back using *getItem().get()* to retrieve it. The problem is that *getItem()* returns a ObservableList of type MenuItem, and not CustomMenuItem. While CustomMenuItem is a child class of MenuItem, I cannot use *getContent()* method that is unique to CustomMenuItem to *addEventListener()* for the inner node, which is Label in your case. Downcasting MenuItem to CustomMenuItem would also give an error.
IDE does not recognize the true type of whatever returned from get() at compile, but only at runtime